# Selecting min() together with other table

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table of countries and their GDP. I want to print the lowes BIP and the countrie

So I typed in

```
select min(GDP), Name from table
```

I get the lowest GDP but the wrong Name (It takes the first name of the out of the table) I tried group by but it showd me of cource all countries but I want only one countrie with the lowest GDP and its GDP in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the first row like below after ordering:

```
select top 1 name, min(gdp)
from table
group by name
order by min(gdp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the minimum GPD as a subquery to filter.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
WHERE
    GPD = (SELECT MIN(GPD) FROM table)
LIMIT
    1
```

Comment: Thanks alot I dindnd leard about subquerys before. Superusefull sorry for my noob question I tryed to use the search but I was not sure what I need to search for ...